# UITableView with gesturerecognizer on several views in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I try to use gestureRecognizer on several elements in my custom tableView with a custom cell.

I have two imageViews linked to specific actions.
If I don't touch these images I want to color the cell's background.

So the code must not be in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

I try something like this but for the program its appears that the images are never touched.

Where I misunderstood ?

```
class MyTableExampleViewController: UIViewController, UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Gesture recognizer
    let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGestureRecognizer:")
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}


...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:CustomExampleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomExampleCell") as! CustomExampleCell

    cell.playImageView.image = UIImage(named: play)
    cell.stopImageView.image = UIImage(named: stop)

    return cell
}


func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint:CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(touchPoint)

    let cell:CustomExampleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomExampleCell") as! CustomExampleCell

    if let _ = cell.playImageView.layer.hitTest(touchPoint) {
        print("Action Play")
    } else if let _ = cell.stopImageView.layer.hitTest(touchPoint) {
        print("Action Stop")
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

}



}
```

Comment: Why don't you use to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: I tried it but when it change the background color when I touch the image in the cell

Comment: It's the same as I have 2 buttons in my cell. If I don't click on one of these then the cell's background color must change

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the touch in the CustomExampleCell. Then implement a delegate to inform your viewcontroller if you need it.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit plz ?

Comment: What do you want to know? I think my answer is clear

Comment: A kind of example ? I really don't know how to implement your answer.
I must implement touchesBegan in CustomExampleCell and not gestureRecognizer ?

Comment: You can implement what you want. Just to it in the Cell and not your viewcontroller. Maybe this helps: http://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1 Its a tutorial for a to-do App where gesture Recognizer are implementent for each cell and when used the viewcontroller gets informed via the delegate